# Google Analytics data from previous years/months has changed

Tags: google-analytics, page-views

We use Google Analytics to get stats for reporting at the end of each year. After taking all the statistics for 2016, I have entered same date range in (Jan 1 2016 - Dec 31 2016) months later and all of the data has increased quite significantly. For example, total page views for the year were 16,000 and now they are 18,400???

Can anyone advise why it is doing this or at least if it is normal?

Comment: It is not normal; Google makes it quite clear that once data is collected, it cannot be changed. The date range is the same, but what about the other filters?